# When I change my kernel 4.12.5, I can't boot the system

Tags: boot, kernel, compiling

My error information picture link:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SbKZ.jpg]

I compiled the Kernel steps:

1. Download the sources code.
2. Config the compile environment:`apt-get install kernel-package build-essential libncurses5-dev fakeroot`
3. decompress the source code to /usr/src.
4. `sudo xz -d patch-4.12.5.xz|pathc -p1`
5. copy the previous kernel configure file:`cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`
6. `cd /usr/src/linux-4.12.5`, run:`make menuconfig`.
   load→OK→Save→OK→EXIT→EXIT
7. `make bzImage -j4`(because my computer core is 2),then `make modules -j4`
8. `make modules_install` , then `make install`
9. `sudo mkinitramfs 4.12.5 -o /boot/initrd.img-4.12.5`, then `sudo update-grub`.

This is the whole process of my compile kernel. Why does the strange problem occur?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Do you really have a printer attached to a parallel port? ie Dot Matrix Epson or Okidata or ancient HP LaserJet III  something like that?

Comment: `4.12.5` must be relatively new because the last one I installed was `4.12.4` a couple of days ago. Is there a particular reason why you picked this kernel version? Can you try an earlier version and boot ok with it instead?

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have attempt to several kernel version, including `4.12.X`,`4.11.X`,`4.10.X` and so on. But only the `4.4.44` ,`4.4.8`,` 4.6.X ` can succeed. My computer brand is Acer E 14. Actually, you may not hear it.

Comment: I haven't a printer attached to a parallel port.The reason why I change my kernel is that my computer often cannot resume after suspend. The method to solve this problem is to

Comment: I have not a printer attached to parallel port. The new stable kernel means more secure.